# Google Spreadsheet: Hide/Unhide any row that meets x condition in a group of rows when clicking button?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When clicking "button1" I would like the code to check the First Cell (Column A) of Rows 38-58 and hide the Row if the corresponding cell is empty and show if it isn't.

Empty in this case means the cell still has a formula but is just blank. If that's not possible, the "Hide Condition" can be Cells that are not a number.

I'd like to combine it with the code below, which hides and shows Rows 10 and 11 when Cell C4 and D4 equal 0 respectively.

```
function button2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var cellRef1 = "C4";
  var cellRef2 = "D4";
  var cell1 = sheet.getRange(cellRef1);
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange(cellRef2);
  var value1 = cell1.getValue();
  var value2 = cell2.getValue();
  
  if (value1 == "0"){
    sheet.hideRows(10);
  }
  if (value2 == "0"){
    sheet.hideRows(11);
  }
  if (value1 != "0"){
    sheet.showRows(10);
  }
  if (value2 != "0"){
    sheet.showRows(11);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide/unhide the rows this way:

```
function hide_unhide_rows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getRange('a38:a58').getDisplayValues().flat();

  rows.forEach((cell_value,i) => {
    let index = i+38;
    if (cell_value == '' && !sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(index)) sheet.hideRows(index);
    if (cell_value != '' &&  sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(index)) sheet.unhideRows(index);
  });
}
```

As for the how it can be combine with your code, you can just add at the end of your function this line:

```
hide_unhide_rows();
```

Or, here is the full combined code:

```
function button2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value1 = sheet.getRange('c4').getValue();
  var value2 = sheet.getRange('d4').getValue();
  
  if (value1 == 0) { sheet.hideRows(10) } else { sheet.showRows(10) }
  if (value2 == 0) { sheet.hideRows(11) } else { sheet.showRows(11) }

  var rows = sheet.getRange('a38:a58').getDisplayValues().flat();

  rows.forEach((cell_value, i) => {
    let index = i+38;
    if (cell_value == '' && !sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(index)) sheet.hideRows(index);
    if (cell_value != '' &&  sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(index)) sheet.unhideRows(index);
  });
}
```

**Update**

If you have several ranges to process, you have to change several lines in the code this way:

```
function button(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var value1 = sheet.getRange('c4').getValue();
  var value2 = sheet.getRange('d4').getValue();

  if (value1 == 0) { sheet.hideRows(10) } else { sheet.showRows(10) }
  if (value2 == 0) { sheet.hideRows(11) } else { sheet.showRows(11) }
  
  var list = ['a27:a29','a41:a60','a66:a85']; // <----------------- here
  var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(list).getRanges(); // <------- here
  for (var range in rangeList){
    var rows = rangeList[range].getDisplayValues().flat();
    var shift = +list[range].split(':')[0].slice(1); // <---------- here

    rows.forEach((cell_value, i) => {
      let index = (i + shift); // <-------------------------------- here
      if (cell_value == '' && !sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(index)) sheet.hideRows(index);
      if (cell_value != '' &&  sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(index)) sheet.showRows(index);
    
    });
  }
}
```

If you have too many ranges the code can work slowly. There is a way to improve it a bit. But the hide/unhide operation is sluggish by design. So the code will be quite slow anyway.

Comment: Hi, @TheDeterminer, I see you're trying to ask (?) how you could process several ranges. Your code looks more or less fine, does it work? (I haven't tried it yet.) But it's an extremely weird way to ask via editing existing answers. I'd propose you to ask a new question.

Comment: Just in case, perhaps this will work: http://pastie.org/p/366vn5k3qv50Ubju9gaI0Q